# Java: calling the base method class from a second derived class

Tags: java, class

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
class A {
    void myMethod() {
        // execute A
    }
}

class B extends A {
    void myMethod() {
        // execute B
    }
}

class C extends B {
    void myMethod() {
        // execute C
        // execute myMethod in A, without touching myMethod in B OR both
    }
}
```

I'd like to do this conditionally, that is sometimes call what's in `myMethod` inside `B` and other times not, but always call `myMethod` inside `A`.

By calling `super.myMethod()` in `C` I get `myMethod` of `B`, but I only want `myMethod` of `A`. Is that possible? I've heard of "virtual" things, but I don't know how to use them... yet.

Comment: Sounds more like a design issue. In any case, you can call `super` to get B's method, and use logic inside B's method to determine if it should call *its* super (A's method) in addition to running its own logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible in Java on purpose. Class `B` overrides and therefore hides the implementation of `myMethod` in `A` from further deriving classes. Allowing `C` to call `myMethod` of `A` would violate this encapsulation. Consider a case where `B.myMethod` performs some updates before internally calling `A.myMethod` which are important for the correct functionality of `B`. Without these updates, the contract of `B` could be violated. Therefore, it should not be possible to call `A.myMethod` in a derived class without calling `B.myMethod`.

Usually, your design is flawed if you want to do stuff like this.

Of course, you can do stuff like suggested by Dave in the comments: You can alter the implementation of `B.myMethod` to call `A.myMethod`. This is okay, because `B` retains the control over when to call `A.myMethod`. Therefore, it can take care that its contract is not violated.

Another idea is to factor out the behaviour you want from `A` into another method and call this one.

Comment: I agree, but somehow it turned out this way, I'll find another way to do whatever I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this, `A.myMethod()` probably does too much. Try to refactor it into several smaller methods with access level `protected`.

That allows you to call these methods from both `B` and `C`.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with most answers about possibly changing the design, to directly answer you could pass in a variable boolean into the first method. The entirety of the logic in B's method should depend on a conditional if statement depending on the boolean. Make sure to make a call to super.myMethod() outside of this if statement.

Something like this:

```
void myMethod(boolean execB) {
// execute B
super.myMethod(execB);
    if(execB)
    {
        //B logic
    }
}
```

This is however, not the best in practice, because only B's method is using the variable, hence why refactoring the design  might be a good decision.